# Mat-Select select currently selected option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I need to react on option selection. My problem is that this component is not emitting event (`selectionChange` output is not emitting new events) when I have selected option A, and I open select pane and select option A again. The event is not fired because selection is not changed but I need in my use case to fire an selection change event in this case. Does somebody know how to do this? Is there any way to override `selectionModel` in this `mat-select` component? I have a list of links and after selecting any of them I need to react even when user select the same link again. I'm using `@angular/core@5.2.5` and `@angular/material@5.2.1`.

Here is the template with this component that I want to use:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Search history"
        [disabled]="(links | async).length === 0"
        [value]="(links | async).length > 0 ? (links | async)[0] : null"
        (selectionChange)="onSearchHistorySelect($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let l of links | async" [value]="l">{{l.title}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Use an empty option to start with, or make your own component. But I'm not even sure that HTML allows what you want, I think you can't trigger an event on same option change.

Comment: If you are using `[ngModel]` then it'll support `(ngModelChange)`.  try that then.

Comment: I'm not using any forms and model for this. Just link selector for navigation. I updated question with template.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to your option, so the function will be called even if the option is already selected.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="status">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value (click)="myFunction()">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The only problem I found with this is that you can't give the value of the selected option to the function (or at least I didn't find a way). But you can work around that by binding the value to a property in your class with ngModel.

Then in your function you can just call this property (in my case this.status).

```
myFunction() {
  console.log(this.status);  // Do stuff with your selected value
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have a feeling that this will not work with selecting by using keyboard only.

Comment: You can pass selected `option` to the function by using it like this. If `option` is scoped variable in the `*ngFor` loop and in Your example it is: `(click)="myFunction(option)"`